# Angular multiple projects tslint rule configuration

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, tslint

I have to configure tslint rules in angular project.
my project structure is **monorepo**.[my angular project directory structure,please ignore spell mistake *projectapp1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZJEx.png)

this is my project structure.

1. src->projectapp1
2. src->projectapp2
3. how to configure tslint rules in angular.json for this directory structure
   (please ignore TestApp1 (emptyfolder))

Comment: what is the issue, tslint is not checking for nexted apps ?

Comment: yes, tslint is not checking nested apps.